# Kibana/Elastic export all data without size limit from data table visualization using Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to export all available data from [this public Kibana/Elastic data table](https://hex.vision/app/visualize#/edit/e8d56a50-3367-11ea-8d7f-a79593d8efcc?_g=(filters:!(),query:(language:kuery,query:%27%27),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-30d,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((%27$state%27:(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:ff35cce0-25ac-11ea-b36a-afff3b35cff3,key:end,negate:!t,type:exists,value:exists),query:(exists:(field:end))),(%27$state%27:(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:ff35cce0-25ac-11ea-b36a-afff3b35cff3,key:expectedEnd,negate:!f,params:(gte:now,lt:now%2B5555d),type:range),query:(range:(expectedEnd:(gte:now,lt:now%2B5555d))))),linked:!f,query:(language:kuery,query:%27%27),uiState:(vis:(params:(colWidth:!((colIndex:0,width:434.5)),sort:(columnIndex:1,direction:desc)))),vis:(aggs:!((enabled:!t,id:%272%27,params:(customLabel:%27Staker%20Address%27,field:stakerAddr,missingBucket:!f,missingBucketLabel:Missing,order:desc,orderBy:%271%27,otherBucket:!f,otherBucketLabel:Other,size:100),schema:bucket,type:terms),(enabled:!t,id:%275%27,params:(customLabel:%27%23%20of%20Open%20Stakes%27,field:stakeId),schema:metric,type:cardinality),(enabled:!t,id:%276%27,params:(customLabel:%27Average%20Staked%20Days%27,field:stakedDays),schema:metric,type:avg),(enabled:!t,id:%273%27,params:(customLabel:%27HEX%20Staked%27,field:hexStaked),schema:metric,type:sum),(enabled:!t,id:%271%27,params:(customLabel:%27HEX%20Staked%20Shares%27,field:hexStakeShares),schema:metric,type:sum),(enabled:!t,id:%274%27,params:(customLabel:%27HEX%20Penalty%20Paid%27,field:hexPenalty),schema:metric,type:sum)),params:(autoFitRowToContent:!f,dimensions:(buckets:!((accessor:0,aggType:terms,format:(id:terms,params:(id:string,missingBucketLabel:Missing,otherBucketLabel:Other)),params:())),metrics:!((accessor:1,aggType:cardinality,format:(id:number),params:()),(accessor:2,aggType:avg,format:(id:number,params:(pattern:%270,0%27)),params:()),(accessor:3,aggType:sum,format:(id:number,params:(pattern:%270,0%27)),params:()),(accessor:4,aggType:sum,format:(id:number,params:(pattern:%270,0%27)),params:()),(accessor:5,aggType:sum,format:(id:number,params:(pattern:%270,0%27)),params:()))),perPage:12,percentageCol:%27%27,showMetricsAtAllLevels:!f,showPartialRows:!f,showToolbar:!t,showTotal:!f,sort:(columnIndex:!n,direction:!n),totalFunc:sum),title:%27Stake%20-%20Open%20Stake%20Leaderboard%27,type:table))) to a .csv file. However, using the export-button only gives me 7735 entries while there are many more. I assume this has to do something with an export size limit. Is there a method to obtain all entries?

I already tried the Elasticsearch Python package, but it appears I need the API key for this (which I don't have as I'm not the creator). Does anyone have other suggestions I could try? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can contact the creator and ask if they will give you an API key

Comment: if you want export all entries you must do it with a search and not with visualize. The result of a visualize is an aggregation that's why you haven't an entrie per line